# Tensorflow: Apply boolean mask on variable of unvalidated shape?

Tags: tensorflow

Ok, so following scenario: I have a variable `var` whose rank is fixed but whose shape is not. For example, it could be a 1D-tensor of arbitrary length. I want to initialize `var` once at the beginning of a session with my graph. I use a placeholder that is attached to this variable to do this (see also in the code below). Then I do some computations in my graph and at some point I need to extract, say, all values greater than 0 from `var`, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf    

init_var = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[None])
var = tf.Variable(init_var,dtype=tf.float64,validate_shape=False)
booled = tf.boolean_mask(var, var>0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), { init_var: [1,-2,3] } )
    print sess.run([booled])
```

But this yields the ValueError-Exception:

```
ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, 
even if some dimensions are None. 
E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.
```

Now, this exception goes away if I set validate_shape to True but then I'd need to fix the shape of `var` at graph construction time but I want it to be dynamic. Nevertheless, if anyone knows how to either evaluate boolean masks on variables of unvalidated shape OR how to reinitialize the shape of `var` each session (maybe without reconstructing the whole graph), I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved it meanwhile and it turns out that the solution is *incredibly* simple. While it seems to be impossible to specify a shape with 'None' entries when defining a variable (and thus to specify just its rank), it is possible to do it right after with `var.set_shape()` like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf    

init_var = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[None])
var = tf.Variable(init_var,dtype=tf.float64,validate_shape=False)
var.set_shape([None])
booled = tf.boolean_mask(var, var>0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), { init_var: [1,-2,3] } )
    print sess.run([booled])
```

Now it runs fantastically right into the arms of my expectation!

Comment: `var.set_shape([None])` sure did solve my problem with `boolean_mask`.